# create a dictionary from columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a data frame containing 3 columns,
column 1: having names
column 2: having items stored in lists
column 3: having items stores in lists

---

```
    columns                                 row_index                       values
0   A                                          []                             []
1   B                                          []                             []
2   C                                       [12, 32]                      [abc, def]
3   D                                          []                             []
4   E                                       [65, 78]                      [qrst, xyz]
```

I want to create a dictionary such that the output looks like as follows:

```
{C:{12:abc ,32:def},
 E:{65:qrst,78:xyz}}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why did first two rows get skipped and `D` is kept?

Comment: this is just a sample of what the output looks like rows A and B should also be a part of the dictionary as well

Comment: Please then update your output accordingly. Also, `{[]:[]}` is not a valid dict since `list` is unhashable. Do you want empty `dict` instead?

Comment: then, in that case only the rows where len>0 would also do

Answer (score 0):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.apply` with `to_dict`:

```
new_df = df[df['values'].str.len().gt(0)].set_index('columns')
result = new_df.apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x["row_index"], x["values"])), 1).to_dict()
print(result)
```

Output:

```
{'C': {12: 'abc', 32: 'def'}, 
 'E': {65: 'qrst', 78: 'xyz'}}
```